# Read .csv and combine duplicate columns - pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a .csv file with 893 columns that I need to read into pandas (or R) to analyze. When the spreadsheet is generated it creates duplicate columns that need to be combined into one.

The problem I am having is that when I read the .csv into pandas or R to create a dataframe it automatically assigns a number to each additional duplicate column meaning they can't be grouped easily.

The original data is formatted like this:

```
****** PYTHON ******

!!!EXAMPLE!!!

import pandas as pd 

d = {'Name':["Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim",
                                "Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue"],
                       "Dates":["2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                                 "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28",
                                 "2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                                 "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28"],
                       "Event" : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       "Event" : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       "Event" : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

d = pd.DataFrame(d)

d

****** R ******

df_date <- data.frame( Name = c("Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim",
                                "Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue"),
                       Dates = c("2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                                 "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28",
                                 "2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                                 "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28"),
                       Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                       Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                       Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

FYI - this is just an example. The real data will be read in from a .csv file using `df = pd.read_csv("dummy.csv")` or equivalent.

Is there any method to either;

1. Read in a .csv and maintain the duplicate column names so they can be grouped and analyzed

or

2. Group the duplicate column names at the point of reading the .csv in so they can be analyzed as one column

N.B: Interestingly I noticed when making the example that it won't even allow me to create a dataframe with columns the same name.

Comment: The issue in Python is not `pandas`. Try printing your Python dictionary. It will only have one value for `'Event'`. Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. Pandas and R will both allow duplicate column names if you assign them after they are created, e.g. `df.columns = ['a', 'a']` in Python or `colnames(df) <- c("a", "a")` in R. In both cases though it is a bad idea and will break things if you try to do operations later. This is not what data frames are for If you have to read in your data from a csv, read it without headers and rename the columns yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SamR, the dictionary is just for the purpose or the example. In reality I am reading i a csv file with 893 columns. Unfortunately this won't address the issue I am having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a dict where the keys are not unique, so this can't be created in the form you want it to be (the values are just overwritten with the last one). The dict itself is then correctly handed to pandas and used to create the DataFrame.

You could use for example a different method of adding the extra columns where you can explicitly allow duplicates.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ["Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim", "Jim",
              "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue", "Sue"],
     "Dates": ["2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5", "2010-01-17", "2010-01-20",
               "2010-01-29", "2010-02-6", "2010-02-9", "2010-02-16", "2010-02-28",
               "2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5", "2010-01-17", "2010-01-20",
               "2010-01-29", "2010-02-6", "2010-02-9", "2010-02-16", "2010-02-28"],
     "Event": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}

d = pd.DataFrame(d)
d.insert(len(d.columns), "Event", [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], allow_duplicates=True)
d.insert(len(d.columns), "Event", [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], allow_duplicates=True)
```

Which gives you:

```
>    Name       Dates  Event  Event  Event
  0   Jim    2010-1-1      1      1      1
  1   Jim    2010-1-2      1      1      1
  2   Jim   2010-01-5      1      1      1
  3   Jim  2010-01-17      1      1      1
  4   Jim  2010-01-20      1      1      1
  5   Jim  2010-01-29      1      1      1
  6   Jim   2010-02-6      1      1      1
  7   Jim   2010-02-9      1      1      1
  8   Jim  2010-02-16      1      1      1
  9   Jim  2010-02-28      1      1      1
  10  Sue    2010-1-1      1      1      1
  11  Sue    2010-1-2      1      1      1
  12  Sue   2010-01-5      1      1      1
  13  Sue  2010-01-17      1      1      1
  14  Sue  2010-01-20      1      1      1
  15  Sue  2010-01-29      1      1      1
  16  Sue   2010-02-6      1      1      1
  17  Sue   2010-02-9      1      1      1
  18  Sue  2010-02-16      1      1      1
  19  Sue  2010-02-28      1      1      1
```

#### Edit:

If the columns exist but they just have an unwanted numbering `[.1, .2, ...]` you can use the `re` package:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", sep=";")
>    a  b  b.1  b.2
  0  a  1    5    7
  1  b  2    5    7
  2  c  3    6    7
  3  d  4    7    7
  4  e  5    8    7

df.columns = [re.sub("(.*?)(\.\d+)", "\\1", c) for c in df.columns]
>    a  b  b  b
  0  a  1  5  7
  1  b  2  5  7
  2  c  3  6  7
  3  d  4  7  7
  4  e  5  8  7
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ewz93, the dictionary is just for the purpose or the example. In reality I am reading i a csv file with 893 columns. Unfortunately this won't address the issue I am having.

Comment: So you mean after you read it the columns are there but named wrong, like `["Event", "Event.1", "Event.2", ...]`, right? In this case just fixing the column names should be much easier. Check my edit.

Comment: Ah, regular expressions.. of course! Thanks. Changed my vote.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to apply these reg ex in R?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with R but it should be somewhat similar and you probably have to use this method https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html. Although I'm not sure how to replace all column names at once in R. Also not sure if R allows multiple columns with the same name. Pandas explicitly does allow it while discouraging from using it so that is more a design decision.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest this solution:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Name;Dates;Event;Event;Event
Jim;2010-1-1;1;1;1
Jim;2010-1-2;1;1;1
Jim;2010-01-5;1;1;1
Jim;2010-01-17;1;1;1
Jim;2010-01-20;1;1;1
Jim;2010-01-29;1;1;1
Jim;2010-02-6;1;1;1
Jim;2010-02-9;1;1;1
Jim;2010-02-16;1;1;1
Jim;2010-02-28;1;1;1
Sue;2010-1-1;1;1;1
Sue;2010-1-2;1;1;1
Sue;2010-01-5;1;1;1
Sue;2010-01-17;1;1;1
Sue;2010-01-20;1;1;1
Sue;2010-01-29;1;1;1
Sue;2010-02-6;1;1;1
Sue;2010-02-9;1;1;1
Sue;2010-02-16;1;1;1
Sue;2010-02-28;1;1;1
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';')
df.rename(columns={col:col.split('.')[0] for col in df.columns}, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Name       Dates  Event  Event  Event
0   Jim    2010-1-1      1      1      1
1   Jim    2010-1-2      1      1      1
2   Jim   2010-01-5      1      1      1
3   Jim  2010-01-17      1      1      1
4   Jim  2010-01-20      1      1      1
5   Jim  2010-01-29      1      1      1
6   Jim   2010-02-6      1      1      1
7   Jim   2010-02-9      1      1      1
8   Jim  2010-02-16      1      1      1
9   Jim  2010-02-28      1      1      1
10  Sue    2010-1-1      1      1      1
11  Sue    2010-1-2      1      1      1
12  Sue   2010-01-5      1      1      1
13  Sue  2010-01-17      1      1      1
14  Sue  2010-01-20      1      1      1
15  Sue  2010-01-29      1      1      1
16  Sue   2010-02-6      1      1      1
17  Sue   2010-02-9      1      1      1
18  Sue  2010-02-16      1      1      1
19  Sue  2010-02-28      1      1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was having a similar problem, searched for hours for a solution, and found nothing. I think your initial question also included that the duplicated columns "need to be combined into one", which is something not addressed on previous answers. So I wanted to share what I did! After loading your df, using aggregate_labels(df) should get you what you wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')

def list_destroyer(df):
    for column in df.axes[1]:
        for element in range(len(df[column])):
            if type(df[column][element]) == type(list()):
                if len(df[column][element]) == 1:
                    df[column][element] = df[column][element][0]


def nan_destroyer(df):
    for column in df.axes[1]:
        for element in range(len(df[column])):
            if type(df[column][element]) == type(list()):
                nan_indexes = []
                for i in range(len(df[column][element])):
                    if pd.isnull(df[column][element][i]):
                        nan_indexes.append(i)
                for j in sorted(nan_indexes, reverse=True):
                    del df[column][element][j]


def add_nan_rows(df, num_rows):
    while len(df) < num_rows:
        df.loc[len(df)] = pd.Series(dtype='float64')


def clean_nan(df):
    df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all', inplace = True)


def aggregate_labels(df):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[0]
    df = df.groupby(by=df.columns.values, axis=1).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values.tolist()))
    nan_destroyer(df)
    list_destroyer(df)
    for columna in df.axes[1]:
        exploded = df[columna].explode(columna)
        add_nan_rows(df,len(exploded))
        df[columna] = exploded
    clean_nan(df)
    return df


df_clean = aggregate_labels(df)
```

Regards!